# Switching from Netbeans 8.2 to Apache Netbeans 10 for PHP Development

Tags: php, netbeans, glassfish

Currently I'm using the **Netbeans version 8.2** for PHP developing purposes. I'm in need of finding whether switching to **Apache Netbeans version 10** will create any conflicts and issues in 'Glassfish server based PHP projects' that I  have partially completed in Netbeans version 8.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No... There won't be any issue in doing the aforementioned switch..

Answer (score 1):

Here you get a really short answer: no.

Comment: Seconded, as long as you can twist the arm of QA into reclassifying the 1500 item and growing bugtracking system containing regressions, bugs and fatal crashes and reclassify them all as "features" and marking them all resolved.  Case closed.

Comment: This does provide an answer to the question because it is a yes/no-question.

Comment: Working around with the new Netbeans IDE.. Seems to be working well up until now..